# Match strings after multiline pattern of texts

Tags: bash, expect, tclsh

I need to extract the value of "Manage VLAN" from the below output with regular expressions and store the value inside a variable to be used later in my script.

```bash
set switch 100.10.100.100
set Username "test"
set Password "test"

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $Username@$switch
expect "*assword: "
send "$Password\r"
expect *>
send "enable\r"
expect "*#"
send "config\r"
expect "(config)#"
send "display something"
```

The output will be:

```
status             : Connected 
IP Address         : 2.2.2.2 
Mask               : 255.255.255.255 
Gateway            : 2.2.2.1 
Manage VLAN        : 456 
Manage priority    : 0 
Option60           : No 
Switch             : Enable
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to suppress the output or retain the output and extract the needed data simultaneously?

Comment: I want to supress all the output and just extract the value from Manage VLAN field and assign that value into the variable..

Comment: are you limited to what tools you are using? I can't be certain that you don't want something internal to `expect`. If not, then `awk '/Manage VLAN/{print $3}` will print the value. Not sure about storing vars in `tclsh`, but maybe `set val = \`awk ....\`` ? If you don't recognize the back-tics, search for and read about command substitution. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

See example:

```
expect1.1> spawn bash -c "echo vlan : 1234"
spawn bash -c echo vlan : 1234
22902
expect1.2> expect -re {vlan *: *([0-9]+)}
vlan : 1234
expect1.4> set vlanid $expect_out(1,string)
1234
expect1.5> puts $vlanid
1234
expect1.6>
```